# For loop not going after 20 or some time repeat 11 to 20

Tags: php

my below code not print url after 20 time.In other world not work for loop after 20 interval. Some time not working after 20 interval or some time repeat 11 to 20 every time.Pleas give me solution of this error. what's problem in below code?

```
for($z=0;$z<=50;$z++)
{
    $url = 'http://xxxxxxx.com/xzxzxzxz.php?id='.$z;

    $html = new DOMDocument();
    @$html->loadHtmlFile($url);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
    $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='dark']//a/@href" );

    foreach ($nodelist as $n)
    {
        $a[]=$n->nodeValue;
    }

    $n1 = count($a);
    for($i=0;$i<=$n1;$i++)
    {
        if($i == 3)
        {
            echo $a[$i]."<br>";
            $url48 = $a[$i];
        }

        if($i == 4)
        {
            echo $a[$i]."<br>";
            $url128 = $a[$i];
        }
    }

    unset($n);
    $n = array();
    unset($a);
    $a = array();
}
```

Comment: You might be rate limited by the server you're requesting data from, especially if it's requesting so many times in a small amount of time. Ways around that? Maybe try putting a `sleep` in for a couple of seconds each time to keep the requests per second/minute down

Comment: Isn't the iteration loop depend on the  number of items extracted by the given xPath ?

Comment: Have you verified that the target dom is actually being processed as you expect? What warnings led you to `@$html` ?